# Configuring log4net for generating rolling log files with roll numbers separated by underscore

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am using RollingFileAppender to generate log files in my application. The generated file names are `MyApp.log`, `MyApp.1.log`, `MyApp.2.log`... and so on.

I want them like `MyApp_1.log`, `MyApp_2.log`, `MyApp_3.log`... and so on.
How can we achieve this?

My log4net appender configuration looks like -

```xml
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value=".\\Logs\\MyApp.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="15360KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %message%-5level%newline" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to configure the appender the way you want. You could copy the source code of the rolling file appender and modify it so that the appender behaves as required. You have to be a bit careful though because there are several places in the source code that depends on the file names being as they currently are, but it can be done of course.